# unable to read POST parameters in spring application

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs, spring

I m using angular js for posting parameters to spring application.

At angular side

```
$http.post('dashboard/processSearch',{processRequestName:'TestName',displayName:'Test'})
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

At controller side in spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String searchAll(@RequestParam String processRequestName, @RequestParam String displayName) {

    return processRequestName+"####"+displayName;
}
```

I m getting complete webpage in ajax response with error message

Error
    Application encountered an error while performing the operation. 
    See error details below.
    Error Reference: 1459234251503-5

```
label.error.missingservletrequestparameterexception
```

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to determine if it's a client- or server-side-oriented problem.

Comment: Its server side problem. able to see post params in firebug

Comment: In this case you'll need to include the exact stack trace which will explain in detail what the problem was and where.

Comment: in ajax response I m getting 


Error
   Application encountered an error while performing the operation. See error details below.

   Error Reference: 1459322087568-4

   label.error.missingservletrequestparameterexception

   or use the button below to send an error report to support

Comment: This is not the server-side error stack trace. The info you included is still completely useless.

Answer (score 2):

## Specify the params argument

Break your http call down differently.

```
$http({
  url: dashboard/processSearch, 
  method: "POST",
  params: {processRequestName: 'TestName', displayName:'Test'}
});
```

This is the correct way to pass params.

But you might need to pass headers in a similar way to the params

```
headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
}
```

## Use a factory

Also you should make http requests in a factory method that returns the result. You can then add that factory to any controller you need. This is where you do the `.then` part of your controller.

Your factory should look something like this

```
angular.module('yourService', []).factory('YourFactory', [ '$http',  function($http){
  return{
    getStuff: function(){
        return // your http request
    }
  };
}]);
```

You can then call your factory in your controller like this

```
angular.module('yourCtrlMod', ['yourService']).controller('yourCtrl', [ '$scope','yourFactory', function($scope, yourFactory){

  yourFactory.getStuff().then(function(res){
    $scope.yourScope= res.data; 
  });

}]);
```

Note that this is for a get not a post, in your case you will have to post the data and send arguments. to the factory and fill out the params or headers.

Comment: Thanks for corrected me at angular side. what about spring? Is there any changes needed there

Comment: no problems Nitin, I'm not familiar with Spring but I hope that this answer pushes you in the right direction, best of luck.